# Something going wrong with this Query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am breaking my head behind it from last 30 mins but i don't where i am doing mistake. i am really got confused between (') and (").

The $arr value contains value that i have checked by printing `echo $arr['given_name']`. so no doubt in $arr's data.

```
 $query="insert into user (fname,lname,email,gender) values('".$arr['given_name']."','".$arr['family_name']."','".$arr['email']."','".$arr['gender']."'";
 mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

i know it's basic question but still i am not able to identify error
Can you please suggest me where i am doing mistake?

Comment: What always helps when debugginh: add an echo $query; to your script, so you can verify what is done there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine you get confused by the brackets, " and '-'s and mis the closing ).

Why don't you use prepared statements? That sorts out your confusing and makes the code way more readable! And you got basic parameter-type checking.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user 
                          (fname,lname,email,gender) 
                          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $arr['given_name'], 
                          $arr['family_name'], 
                          $arr['email'], 
                          $arr['gender']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also make sure you've got some sanitizing and checks build in your complete query.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$query="insert into user (fname,lname,email,gender) values('".$arr['given_name']."','".$arr['family_name']."','".$arr['email']."','".$arr['gender']."')";
```

You're missing an end bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a closing bracket at the end of the values:

```
$query="insert into user (fname,lname,email,gender) values('".$arr['given_name']."','".$arr['family_name']."','".$arr['email']."','".$arr['gender']."')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing closing ) for inserted values?